# viewChild no me recupera los cambios actualizados cuando cargo la pagina

Tags: angular, viewchild

Estoy intentando recuperar el texto seleccionado de un select con viewChild, siempre me devuelve el valor por defecto, el select es un componente angular reutilizable, al cargar la pagina el componente selecciona la opción obtenida de la variable get ,pongo código.

selectReutilizable.html

```
    <select [id]='id'>
    <option value=''>{{defecto}}</option>
    <option *ngFor='let opcion of opciones' [value]='opcion' [selected]='seleccion == opcion'>{{opcion}}</option>
</select>
```

select.html

```
   <app-select-reutilizable #miSelect
   [opciones]="opciones"
   [defecto]="defecto"
   [seleccion]="miVariable"></app-select-reutilizable>
```

select.ts

```
miVariable: string = '';
@ViewChild('miSelect',{static: false, read: ElementRef}) miSelect: ElementRef | undefined;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      console.log(this.miSelect?.nativeElement.childNodes[0].selectedOptions[0].innerHTML);
// me muestra la opción por defecto no la seleccionada
    }

ngOnInit(): void {
  //aquí actualizo 'miVariable' get con la opción que debe seleccionarse por defecto al cargar el componente
}
```

Comment: Quiero añadir que si uso setTimeout con un retraso de 5 segundo, me devuelve el texto seleccionado correctamente. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: El problema que tienes es porque `ngAfterViewInit` sólo se ejecuta una vez. Pero de todas formas, si vas a crear un control de formulario, lo mejor que puedes hacer es mirar como implementar la interfaz `ControlValueAccessor`, para poder usar ese control tanto con los formularios reactivos como con los dirigidos por plantilla.

Comment: se que ngAfterViewInit se ejecuta una vez, pero no me esta mostrando el texto seleccionado, me muestra el texto de la primera opción (la opción por defecto), necesito que me muestre el texto seleccionado una vez ngOnInit actualiza el select.

Comment: Perdona te entendí mal. Y que código tienes en el ngOnInit? Porque si la asignación es síncrona debería logear el valor de miVariable.

Comment: en el ngOnInit capturo el valor de la url cargada algo asi, this.myVariable = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('opcion'); esta variable obtiene el valor correcto, incluso actualiza el select con esa opción seleccionada pero no consigo acceder al texto actualizado en el select ni al valor , nada actualizado.

Comment: además añado que si uso setTime como dije anteriormente , me retorna el valor correcto, el problema es que angular no esta esperando que el select se modifica con la opción seleccionada.

Comment: Pues si todo el código es síncrono es raro que no te lo lea correctamente. Pero una cosa que no alcanzo a comprender, es para que quieres leer el valor del select de esta manera tan enrevesada. Podrías actualizar la pregunta, explicando un poco más detalladamente que es lo que estás intentando implementar, porque prácticamente seguro que hay una forma más sencilla de hacerlo que con ViewChild.

Comment: si tienes razón, hay una manera mas sencilla de hacerlo, igual ya lo hice, pero quiero entender porque no funciona de la manera que lo intente

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema esta en la comunicación entre el padre y el hijo
Ya que Para un mismo componente ViewChild permite acceder a elementos DOM nativos que tienen una variable de referencia de plantilla y modificar su valor con

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someInput.nativeElement.value = 'nuevo Valor';
  }
```

Si tenemos a un componente hijo y el define un metodo

```js
Soy(){
return 'soy el hijo'}
```

Podemos acceder desde el padre con

```js
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.child.Soy()); // soy el  componente hijo !
  }
```

como asi tambien para las  propiedades del hijo
Ahora Si el padre es el responsable de  comunicar al hijo un valor por defecto y el
hijo lo modifica compartira el nuevo dato con al padre con un @Output()
Tener e cuenta que en el caso de un @Input() la comunicación fluye
del padre al hijo y
para ver los cambios en el padre se usa en el hijo

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {...}
```

actualiza los datos antes de que llame ngOnInit
pudiendo recuperar el viejo valor y el nuevo valor
ejemplo [ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LUr2bMQRhhAeuLN3R5B6?p=preview&preview)
Si el hijo es el responsable de comunicar cambios

```js
 newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<tipo>();
 this.newItemEvent.emit(value)
//luego comunicar el nuevo valor al padre
```

O sea el problema para mi esta en el fujo y el ciclo de vida si bien podes mostar  la actualización con un delay no es correcto el binding ni la forma de distribuir la responsabilidad de cada componente por eso lo debes forzar para que te muestre los cambios ya que aunque ViewChild permite acceder a elementos DOM nativos que tienen una variable de referencia de plantilla y actualizar  no esta  para mi bien el codigo este responde a  lo que se le pide por eso ViewChild no recupera los datos al actualizar la pagina

```js
 @Output()
  selectionChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  selectOption(option: string) {
    this.selected = option;
    this.selectionChanged.emit(option);
  }
```

En general la forma de utilizar tu template reference variable miSelect
es desde el componente padre desde la clase del componente padre de esta forma padre.ts

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 // Segun se necesite se puede usar 
  // 1.. @ViewChild('miSelect') miSelect!:PadreHijoComponent ; o //tambien
 @ViewChild('miSelect',{static: false, read: ElementRef}) 
  miSelect!:ElementRef;

  

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {

  }


  ngAfterViewInit(){

 // AQUI SI  ACCEDER A miSelect 

  }


}
```

padre.html

```html
<app-select-reutilizable #miSelect
   [opciones]="opciones"
   [defecto]="defecto"
   [seleccion]="miVariable"></app-select-reutilizable
```